# Load granule subset (tiles) from mosaic based on shapefile footprint (grid) with QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, mosaic

I downloaded DTM *RGE ALTI®* from french IGN [here](https://geoservices.ign.fr/rgealti)
The directory contains a mosaic of granules :
[image]

I would like to load only a subset of the mosaic.

[image]

The dowloaded product contains a shapefile named *dalles* with the footprint of each raster granule. The attribute *name* gives the granule name.

[image]

The *dalle.shp* is in an other subdirectory from *RGEALTI* root directory

[image]

What's the easier way to load only this subset with QGIS?
Does exist a plugin? must i create a VRT (How?)? or use pyqgis? other?

Answer (score 1):

I would build overviews for all rasters (for quicker drawing) then create a vrt.

If you just want to add a subset from a selection you can use pyqgis. Not an easy way but very efficient:

```py
import os
shapelayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("dalles")[0] #Create a layer object from the added extent shapefile
tile_id_column = "NOM_DALLE" #Name of the column with the tile names

#Create a dictionary of all rasters in dem_folder 
#  with the raster name as key and the full path as value.
#  change the path to your path.
dem_folder = r"/home/bera/Downloads/1M-src/RGEALTI_2-0_1M_ASC_LAMB93-IGN69_D003_2023-08-10/RGEALTI/1_DONNEES_LIVRAISON_2023-09-00292/RGEALTI_MNT_1M_ASC_LAMB93_IGN69_D003_20230928/"

dem_dict = {}
for root, folder, files in os.walk(dem_folder): #For all files in dem_folder
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".asc"): #If it is an .asc file
            #Lowercase the filename and remove the .asc part and use as key, the full pathname to it as value:
            dem_dict[file.lower().split(".")[0]] = os.path.join(root, file)

#If you now pass a value from the NOM_DALLE column to dem dict you get the full raster path back:
#print(dem_dict['rgealti_fxx_0644_6589_mnt_lamb93_ign69'])
#/home/bera/Downloads/1M-src/RGEALTI_2-0_1M_ASC_LAMB93-IGN69_D003_2023-08-10/RGEALTI/1_DONNEES_LIVRAISON_2023-09-00292/RGEALTI_MNT_1M_ASC_LAMB93_IGN69_D003_20230928/RGEALTI_FXX_0644_6589_MNT_LAMB93_IGN69.asc

if shapelayer.selectedFeatureCount()>0: #If there are any selected feature in the shapelayer
    rasterlayers = [] #A list to hold raster layers
    for selectedfeature in shapelayer.getSelectedFeatures(): #For each selected feature
        tilenumber = selectedfeature[tile_id_column].lower() #Extract the name from NOM_DALLE column and lowercase it
        if tilenumber in dem_dict: #If the tilenumber is in the dict
            rasterlayer = QgsRasterLayer(dem_dict[tilenumber], tilenumber) #Create a raster layer using the dict
            rasterlayer.setCrs(shapelayer.crs()) #Set its crs (all asc files in my downloads is missing crs)
            rasterlayers.append(rasterlayer) #Append the layer to raster layers list
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(rasterlayers) #Add all layers to the map
```

[image]